# declare promise type in typescript of a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I saw this code somewhere, just curious, why need to specify `Promise` in the return type? isn't the function return data which is an object? and what's the `| null for`?

```
const getSomething = async (
  id: string
): Promise<UserData | null> => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `${API}/user?id=${id}`
    );
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.response) {
      return err.response.data;
    }
    return null;
  }
};
```

Comment: Since that's an async function, it would always returns a promise. The Promise itself resolves to value that is returned by the function since in that case it would be returned a 404 which means the user is not found, then the result type probably null for some reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async functions always return Promises - that way, the asynchronous `await`s can be waited for inside the function, and the result can be used outside the function.

Here, the `getSomething` tries to retrieve data from an axios call. If the call succeeds, the data is just returned:

```
return data;
```

But if the call *doesn't* succeed, it'll return one of the following instead:

```
if (err.response) {
  return err.response.data;
}
return null;
```

If the `axios` call throws, *and* there is no `err.response` property, then `null` will be returned. If you left out the `| null`, the `getSomething` function wouldn't be typed properly.

Comment: is the null make sense here? aren't axios will return the err.response for sure? why the coder make it return null? hmm..

Comment: See the [axios docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors). The response may be empty if the request was made but no response was received, or some other error happened while setting up the request.